# Сайт на flask не загружается

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, site

Начал изучение **flask** по видео *Гоши Дударя*, в первом уроке написали такой сайт:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Default page"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

При запуске **flask** дает эту ссылку для перехода на сайт - http://127.0.0.1:5000
В видео у автора сайт прекрасно запустился и надпись появилась, у меня же почему-то просто бесконечно грузится...

Comment: Как именно было запущено приложение?

Comment: Работаю в thonny ide, обычный запуск

Comment: попробуй:  app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')